# what is difference between set() and word_tokenize()?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize ,word_tokenize

sentence = 'jainmiah I love you but you are not bothering about my request, 
            please yaar consider me for the sake'

word_tok = word_tokenize(sentence)
print(word_tok)

set_all = set(word_tokenize(sentence))
print(set_all)
```

> Actually both word_tokenize() and set(word_tokenize()) both returns
>   same answers what makes the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differences between `word_tokenize` and `set`.

**Word_tokenize**

- Returns a list (try `print(type(word_tok))`)
- Returns all the tokens, regardless if there are duplicates

**Set**

- Returns a set (try `print(type(set_all))`)
- Returns all the **unique** tokens

Try this instead

```
sentence = 'jainmiah jainmiah jainmiah I love you but you are not bothering about my request, please yaar consider me for the sake'

word_tok = word_tokenize(sentence)
print(word_tok)

set_all = set(word_tokenize(sentence))
print(set_all)
```